# Setting div scroll bar as active when main window scroll is at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a page I have div with vertical scroll bar. Main page has it's normal browser scroll bar.
When main window scroll bar is at bottom and user continues to scroll down div vertical scroll bar should continue scrolling.

Is there some jquery event to catch scroll or some other easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes there is a Scroll function in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ Though, I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: no simple answer without a lot more information. Can't do anythng with window scrollbar after it reaches the end except perhaps change the css so there is more page to scroll

Comment: I agree with charlietfl, I think what your saying is possible with jquery and javascript, but I would require some sort of demo or screenshot of what your trying to accomplish to help...